# Python Open and parse a.txt of url one by one

Tags: python, loops, parsing, urllib2

It's an easy and basic question, I guess. But I didn't manage to find a clear and simple answer.
here it's my problem :

I have a .txt file with urls on each line (around 300). I got these urls from a python script.
I would like to open one by one these urls and execute this script for each one to get some informations I am interested by :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-saint-martin-grand-case-ttfg-a413.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
info_tag = soup.find_all('b')
info_nom =info_tag[2].string
info_pos =info_tag[4].next_sibling
info_alt =info_tag[5].next_sibling
info_pis =info_tag[6].next_sibling
info_vil =info_tag[7].next_sibling
print(info_nom +","+ info_pos+","+ info_alt +","+ info_pis +","+info_vil)
```

`aero-url.txt`:

```
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-la-reunion-roland-garros-fmee-a416.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-saint-pierre---pierrefonds-fmep-a417.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/base-aerienne-de-moussoulens-lf34-a433.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aerodrome-d-yvetot-lf7622-a469.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aerodrome-de-dieppe---saint-aubin-lfab-a1.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-calais---dunkerque-lfac-a2.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aerodrome-de-compiegne---margny-lfad-a3.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aerodrome-d-eu---mers---le-treport-lfae-a4.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aerodrome-de-laon---chambry-lfaf-a5.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-peronne---saint-quentin-lfag-a6.html,
http://www.aerodromes.fr/aeroport-de-nangis-les-loges-lfai-a7.html,
...
```

I think i have to use a loop with something like this :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open the file for reading
infile = open("aero-url.txt", 'r')

# Read every single line of the file into an array of lines
lines = infile.readline().rstrip('\n\r')

for line in infile

page = urllib2.urlopen(lines)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

#find the places of each info
info_tag = soup.find_all('b')
info_nom =info_tag[2].string
info_pos =info_tag[4].next_sibling
info_alt =info_tag[5].next_sibling
info_pis =info_tag[6].next_sibling
info_vil =info_tag[7].next_sibling

#Print them on the terminal.
print(info_nom +","+ info_pos+","+ info_alt +","+ info_pis +","+info_vil)
```

I will write these results in a txt file after. But my problem here is how to apply my parsing script to my urls text file.

Comment: `lines` is not a list of lines. As you anyway seem to intend to loop over each line in `infile`, `lines` is not necessary, I believe. Also, you are missing some indentation, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

use `line` instead of `lines` in urlopen

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(line)
```

since you are using `infile` in the loop, you do not need the `lines` line

```
lines = infile.readline().rstrip('\n\r')
```

also indentation is wrong for the loop.
correcting these your code should be like below.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open the file for reading
infile = open("aero-url.txt", 'r')

for line in infile:

    page = urllib2.urlopen(line)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    #find the places of each info
    info_tag = soup.find_all('b')
    info_nom =info_tag[2].string
    info_pos =info_tag[4].next_sibling
    info_alt =info_tag[5].next_sibling
    info_pis =info_tag[6].next_sibling
    info_vil =info_tag[7].next_sibling

    #Print them on the terminal.
    print(info_nom +","+ info_pos+","+ info_alt +","+ info_pis +","+info_vil)
```

Comment: Hi Anbarasan, thank you for your answer. Unfortunetly, i have a syntax error with 'for line in infile' i ll try to find out what's wrong. If u got an idea, i ll take it!

Comment: the colon that should be at the end of the for line is missing.  I have edited the answer to include it.